# Adding view controllers to UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm adding three view controllers to a PageViewController, like so:

```
[pvc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:svc, bvc, tvc, nil] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
```

}];

However, the apps throws an exception and stops on this line. When I check the log navigator, it just says '(lldb)'. What is going wrong?

EDIT: Okay, thanks Paul. I'm quite new to Objective-c; how would implement those methods to get a swipe between my three view controllers?

This is my code in appDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.;

UIPageViewController *pvc = [[UIPageViewController alloc] init]; // Create new PageViewController

BarsViewController *bvc = [[BarsViewController alloc] init]; // Create BarsViewController
StopwatchViewController *svc = [[StopwatchViewController alloc] init]; // Create StopwatchViewController
TimerViewController *tvc = [[TimerViewController alloc] init]; // Create TimerViewController

[pvc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:svc, bvc, tvc, nil] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade]; // Hide status bar

self.window.rootViewController = pvc; // Make tab bar controller the root view controller
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot add 3 viewcontrollers to a uipageviewcontroller. You can either add one viewcontroller, or a maximum of two, depending on the setting of your spine location. SetViewController is a function to add the visible controllers and 2 is the max you can display. Check out the link below, the entry for SetViewController has a chart showing you what controllers you can add depending on the spine location.

[UIPageViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html)

Comment: Oh okay, well what would you recommend I use? I've got these three view controllers and I want to be able to swipe between them. What should I use and how would I go about writing the implementation?

Comment: See Paul Lynch's edited response about implementing the UIPageViewControllerDataSource methods.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. Most probably, one of the view controllers you are adding to the array is nil.

(1b.  Less probably, pvc isn't a `UIPageViewController`.)

1. You need to see the exception details; Xcode 5 has changed behaviour in this regard, and you probably have a breakpoint set for all exceptions.  Just press the continue button a couple of times and it will be displayed in the console window.

EDIT:

OK, so I missed the obvious problem, as reported by the exception - that you can have only one or two view controllers.

Given the error message, you need to implement the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` methods:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = @[svc, bvc, tvc];

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger i = [viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    if (i > 0) i = i - 1;
    return viewControllers[i];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger i = [viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    if (i < ([viewControllers count] + 1)) i = i + 1;
    return viewControllers[i];
}
```

to return the previous and next controllers to support pagination.

Comment: pvc is a UIPageVieController, and I kept pressing the continue button, and the error came up as this: 'The number of provided view controllers (3) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested spine location (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin)'

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've edited my post to ask about the UIPageViewControllerDataSource methods.